# Uncompress file using bunzip2

Tags: command-line, bzip2

I want to decompress a file, I wrote this command:

```
bunzip2 linux-source-4.15.0.tar.bz2
```

and I got this:

```
bunzip2: Input file linux-source-4.15.0.tar.bz2 is not a normal file.
```

I want to know exactly what is the problem.

I ran file `linux-source-4.15.0.tar.bz2` and I got:

```
linux-source-4.15.0.tar.bz2: symbolic link to linux-source-4.15.0/linux-source-4.15.0.tar.bz2
```

Comment: Try running `file  linux-source-4.15.0.tar.bz2` and update the question with the output.

Comment: Same issue: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1113606/configuring-the-kernel-of-recent-version. 1 possible reason: bunzip2 does not understand symlinks and will through that error then.

Comment: I run file linux-source-4.15.0.tar.bz2 and I got linux-source-4.15.0.tar.bz2: symbolic link to linux-source-4.15.0/linux-source-4.15.0.tar.bz2

Answer (score 2):

#### *TL;DR:* You can extract the whole archive with `tar xf`.

As Rinzwind mentioned, `bunzip2` unfortunately refuses to operate on symbolic links. The output of `file` revealed that your `.bz2` file is a symlink rather than a regular file.

How you should go about decompressing the file depends on specifically what you want to do. Considering the particular file you are operating on, it's likely that your `bunzip2` command wouldn't have done quite what you wanted anyway, and that you should extract it with `tar` instead.

### If you want to unpack the tar archive itself

Your `.tar.bz2` file is a tar archive that is bzip2-compressed. You've asked just how to uncompress the file, which you *can* do (see below). But if you do that, the result will be an uncompressed archive, whose contents you'd then likely want to extract.

The `tar` command, which creates and extracts tar archives, can handle compression itself. You can extract the files from this compressed archive the same way you would for an uncompressed tar archive, because `tar` automatically detects and handles compression:

```
tar xf linux-source-4.15.0.tar.bz2
```

You might want to extract the file as your own non-root user, which you can do if you put it somewhere you have write permissions. If this is what you want, I suggest going to the destination and extracting it by giving its full path. For that file, this might be:

```
tar xf /usr/srclinux-source-4.15.0.tar.bz2
```

If you want `tar` to list each file as it extracts it, add the `v` option:

```
tar xvf linux-source-4.15.0.tar.bz2
```

If, for some reason, you wanted to tell `tar` explicitly that the archive you're extracting is bzip2-compressed, you could do so by adding the `j` option:

```
tar xvjf linux-source-4.15.0.tar.bz2
```

(You can use the `v` and `j` options regardless of whether the path that follows the `f` option is absolute or relative.)

### If you want to create a decompressed copy of the file

If you want to decompress the file and place the result in the current directory, you can use `bzcat -d` and redirect the result:

```
bzcat -d linux-source-4.15.0.tar.bz2 >linux-source-4.15.0.tar
```

### If you want to replace the *target* with a decompressed file

If you want to decompress the *target* of the symlink, replacing it with the original (uncompressed) file, then you can use `realpath` to dereference the symlink. In this case, I strongly doubt you want that, but here's what it looks like, for future reference:

```
bunzip2 "$(realpath linux-source-4.15.0.tar.bz2)"
```

Or just find the target and pass it to `bunzip2`, since you should definitely check what the target of a symlink is before performing an operation that removes it and replaces it with something else (in case you're mistaken and the target isn't what/where you think it is). To find the target, you can run that `realpath` command by itself:

```
realpath linux-source-4.15.0.tar.bz2
```

Of course, you can also inspect files with `ls -l`, `file`, and `readlink` to find out if they are symlinks and what their direct target is.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the -f flag will also force bzip2 to handle symlinks: `bunzip2 -f linux-source-4.15.0.tar.bz2`

Comment: Note: it is not specifically about *symlbolic* links. Hard links invoke the same problem.